# C# - How to get List<> object values within the for loop based on List count

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one interface like,

```
public interface Details
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

And i have one method in another class like

```
public void GetDetails()      
{ 
    List<Details> lstDetails = new List<Details>();        
    DetailsImpl objDetailsImpl;
    Details objDetails = new DetailsImpl();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        objDetailsImpl = new DetailsImpl(); //The **DetailsImpl** class is given below
        objDetails.Id = i;
        if(i==1)
           objDetails.Name = "FirstName";
        else
           objDetails.Name = "SecondName";
        lstDetails.Add(objDetails);
    }
    objDetailsImpl.InsertRecords(lstDetails);  
}
```

And i write **InsertRecords** methods in another derived class like,

```
public class DetailsImpl : Details
{
    Dictionary<object, object> objDictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int InsertRecords(List<Details> lstDetails)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstDetails.Count; i++)
        {
            //i want to get the integer value "Id" from List(lstDetails)
            Id = //How to get the Id value based on count, now the <lstDetails> count is 2

            //i want to get the Name object value also, how to i get???
            Name = Convert.ToString(String.Join(",",lstDetails.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray()));
            //If i using the above line for getting **Name** value means, its comes like "FirstName,LastName", but i want **Name** value based on row.....


            objDictionary.Clear();
            objDictionary.Add("@Id",Id);
            objDictionary.Add("@Id",Name);
            //Here i passed this parameter to "ExecuteNonQry" method for insert operations
            ExecuteNonQry("sp_name",objDictonary,CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want to get **Id, Name** object values based on list count. How to i solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by row position?

Comment: Can you give us the definition of the List? the question isn't very clever, expecially what do you mean by "list with some fields", a list can have only one object type so maybe you mean that this object has 2 fields named "name" and "id"?

Comment: Hi... i modified my question... please check now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Name` property of the `i`th element is

```
lstDetails[i].Name
```

It's worth pointing out that you do **not** have a `List<>` you have a `List<T>` - and you're not telling us what the `T` is.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to write

```
String.Join(", ", list.Select(o => o.Name))
```

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - but you've answered the actual question ;-)

Comment: Hi @SLaks.. Thanks for your reply... I used the coding like this   `Name = Convert.ToString(String.Join(",",lstDetails.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray()));`

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju: There is never any reason to call `Convert.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your List has multiple objects of type Detail where Detail is as shown below:

```
public class Detail
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And now you have a list with 2 detail objects in it

```
lstDetails.Add(new Detail(){Id = 1, Name = "John"});
lstDetails.Add(new Detail(){Id = 2, Name = "Charlie"});
```

Now if you want `strValue` to contain `John, Charlie` once the loop is completed you can use the below code without a loop

```
strValue = String.Join(",", lstDetails.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray());
```